# Can I extract tables from PDF using itext 7 in vb.net, if yes then please share some code suggestions

Tags: itext7, pdf-extraction

I need to extract a table from pdf as it is in vb.net using itext7. Please help if it is possible

Comment: most convenient way would be to just use [iText pdf2Data](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/pdf2Data)

Comment: itext pdf2data needs to specify the data fields before extraction. And I have to extract pdf on large scale so I cannot specify data field for each and every pdf.

Comment: if the table structure is always the same, pdf2Data can do it for you (tables can grow and shrink), if you want something else, I think you'd have to develop yourself. Mind you that tables in PDF world, are merely a set of horizontal and vertically positioned text, and potentially lines. The table concept does not really exist in the PDF world.

Comment: Thank you, actually structure of table is not defined in my usecase so I think I have to extract it as text and lines only.

Comment: one good place to start would be these [GitHub examples](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/parse). I will try to come back later with more stuff.

Comment: just noticed you want for .NET. that would be here https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/tree/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/parse